# C# спагетти из списков: оперативная память и производительность

Tags: c#, оптимизация, list, списки

Допустим есть 3 разных класса, A (родительский) и два наследника B и C.

```
public class A { ... };
public class B : A { ... };
public class C : A { ... };
```

Это упрощенная схема, иерархия может быть и сложнее, у B и C могут быть наследники и.т.д. И вопрос в следующем, как лучше всего архитектурно подойти к решению по работе со списками в которых могут фигурировать классы из этой иерархии.

Например, есть списки и метод который добавляет класс B и класс C в список, и соответственно под каждый отдельный список + общий список для A. Выглядит это так:

```
public List<A> AList = new List<A>();
public List<B> BList = new List<B>();
public List<C> CList = new List<C>();

public void Add_B(B obj) {
    AList.Add(obj);
    BList.Add(obj);
}

public void Add_C(C obj) {
    AList.Add(obj);
    CList.Add(obj);
}
```

Является ли это вообще корректным решением? Чем больше классов задействуется в иерархии, тем сильнее это превращается в спагетти из списков, еще и давит на оперативку, но в каком то смысле проще работать с нужными классами.
С другой стороны рассматривается вариант добавлять только в AList, и с помощью "is" определять нужный тип и работать с ним, но влияет ли это на производительность? Какие еще есть варианты для построения работы с массивами объектов-родителей-наследников с которыми работа может быть по отдельности или со всеми сразу?

Comment: Возможно вашу логику можно построить гораздо проще. Скорее всего вам вообще нужен только интерфейс, просто вы его не используете. Возможно вам нужно использовать патерны, которые вам облегчат жизнь. Было бы не плохо что-бы вы пояснили, зачем вам столько списков, может есть другой способ, не использовать множества. а пойти иначе.

Comment: Почему не использовать  `public Dictionary<object, MyClass> Dict = new Dictionary<object, MyClass>();` ? или как подметил @VladimirT использовать интерфейсы.

Comment: @VladimirT интерфейс не пойдет, потому что логика строится по мере продвижения по иерархии. По поводу множества списков, есть сторонний класс который проводит масштабную работу со всей иерархией, включая подсчет количества объектов каждого класса, получение данных, запуск их уникальных методов и.т.п.

Comment: все равно не понятно, почему ваши классы не могут иметь интерфейсы, и почему по ним работать не хотите, это проще и удобнее, тогда у вас получиться, как раз отработка по уникальности, каждый интерфейс, может иметь только свои уникальные методы.

Comment: Нагрузки на оперативную не будет, если это списки классов. По сути списки классов хранят не сами объекты, а ссылки на них, поэтому при добавлении сразу в два списка размер в оперативной памяти увеличится незначительно. И задачу, которую вы так хотите решить стоит озвучить, раз уж спрашиваете, как в таком случае лучше работать со списками.

Comment: @VladimirT если бы был по мимо класса B,C еще был D,E,G, и мне требовалось внести какой-то общий функционал исключительно в B и G, то с удовольствием бы использовал интерфейс, в данном же случае иерархия самодостаточна.

Comment: Наследование ради самого наследования (желание сэкономить в написании пары повторяющихся свойств или методов)? Или же вам реально необходима иерархия классов с которой вы будете работать, а не мучаться уже на старте проекта? И зачем нужно добавлять в две коллекции каждый объект, если достаточно держать одну коллекцию и использовать LINQ для выбора необходимых классов?